# Using zip compression for my iOS app resources?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Wondering about using gzipped resources for my iOS app. The idea is to unzip the resources on first launch to my app's documents directory. I'm hoping this would make downloading our app from the App Store a much smoother/faster experience on-the-go.

Has anyone attempted something like this? If yes, what are the pros/cons? Thanks!

Comment: Often, longer downloading time means bigger app, which, in the eyes of many users, means: "this app is gonna be awesome :D".

Comment: Then you'll really love my first big app: Tokyo Teleport. It's 500MB.

Comment: Not to mention The Elements. Great app. 1 GB.

Comment: ....um, yeah. Plenty of users really don't think bigger apps mean 'this is going to be awesome'. I think 'this app is going to take ages to load, it had better be worth it', which is often followed by, 'what a waste of time'. There is something to be said for instant gratification...

Comment: lxt: Pretty sure we were all kidding!

Comment: really guys... I agree with lxt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.ipa`, which you use for submitting to App Store, is already a `.zip` archive (you can check this by changing the extension), so there really is no point in doing something like this.

It would make sense only for a better compression than `.zip`.